# Editing track names in iTunes made difficult by invisibility of text

Tags: itunes, text

I use iTunes 12.1 on OSX 10.10.3. This has been bugging me for a while but crops up rarely enough not to google it for some time.

The issue is that when I click twice on a track in order to edit the title, the text color changes to white on white background and I can only see the text because it is initially selected. Once I remove the selection, I see nothing at all. See the following gif:
[image]

I did not find a reference to such behaviour on google and am wondering whether this is a universal bug or related to my personal setup. Are there any system settings which could lead to this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like a bug to me. I'd report it to [Apple Bug Report](https://bugreport.apple.com/)

Only seems to do it in Album view when the album's background colour is dark enough that the inverted colour used would be light or white. Then as you edit, you get white on white.

In My Music/Album view, you can see against the album background how/why it may choose the highlight colour [not necessarily the best choice, as the edit background is always white].

In Playlists/Album view you can't see 'why' as the background is always white but it does just the same. It also seems to take a slight swing towards white text compared to the sometimes very light but just about visible colours it chooses in My Music view.

Easiest repro is on an album with no cover image. Does it every time.

Album with purple/yellow predominance as an example…

Music/album view, yellow text
[image]

Playlist/album view, yellow becomes white
[image]

Comment: This seems to have been fixed in 12.2.